# App installed as snap in right-click context menu

Tags: release-loki, camera, context-menu

I've installed Polarr through Snaptastic. When right clicking in Files on an image file, Polarr does not appear in the context menu, not even in View All Applications. How do I put it there? If it will be a feature in Juno, then it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a desktop file and then save it in

~/.local/share/applications

You can create a desktop file reading:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=polarr-snap
Exec=/snap/bin/polarr %u
Type-Application
Icon=polarr
NoDisplay=true
```

Once you create the text file, you can save it as something like polarr-snap.desktop in the ~/.local/share/applications directory.

In educating myself in regards to snap packages, I downloaded the VLC snap in elementary running in a Virtual Machine and was able to add it to the context menu doing the above. I found the answer on another forum but can't find that post so I'm unable to reference it here.

Hope this helps and good luck!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The desktop file was already in ~/.local/share/applications, I've changed some lines, added some others, but I couldn't put the app in the right-click context menu.